# python.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout

Tags: windows, iis-7, python, fastcgi, cgi

I'm trying to host a **Flask (Python)** application on a **Windows** server, but it was giving me
request timeout error, then I changed it to **300 seconds** *(5 minutes)*, and after that, it's giving me an activity timeout error, and I did the same for this, but then also after 5 minutes, it's giving me a request timeout error again.
I've given the correct permissions to **Python** and **ffmpeg** (**ffmpeg** is used in my app).

Here is my **<kbd>web.config</kbd>** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MyApp Handler" 
      path="*" 
      verb="*" 
      modules="FastCgiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe|c:\users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
      resourceType="Unspecified" 
      requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Please let me know if anything else is required in the comments.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ You will get some ideas from this. "We recommend using HttpPlatform to configure your apps, as the WFastCGI project is no longer maintained."

Comment: Hello @LexLi Thanks I'll try provide link solution